# Trouble with with concatenating two strings in to one

Tags: c

I need to write a program that concatenates two strings in to the first string. I can't use a third parameter to hold the new string. When I run the program I get no output, so I'm pretty sure the problem is in my function that concatenates the two strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SZ 81

int concatString(char s1[], char s2[]); // concatenates s2 onto s1, returns length of s1
int getString(char c[], int len);

main(void)
{
    char array1[MAX_SZ * 2];
    char array2[MAX_SZ];
    int string1 = 0;
    int string2 = 0;
    int concat = 0;

    printf("Please String # 1 up to 80 characters long:\n");
    string1 = getString(array1, MAX_SZ);
    printf("Please enter String #2 up to 80 characters long:\n");
    string2 = getString(array2, MAX_SZ);

    concat = concatString(array1, array2);

    printf("You entered \"%s\" (length = %i)\n", array1, concat);

    return 0;
}

int getString(char c[], int len)
{
    int i = 0;
    char d = 0;
    while (d != '\n' && i < len)
    {
        d = getchar();
        c[i++] = d;
    }

    c[--i] = '\0';
    return (i);
}

int concatString(char s1[], char s2[])
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; s1 != '\0'; ++i)
    s1[i] = s1[i];

  for (j = i; s2 != '\0'; ++j)
    s1[j] = s2[j];

  s1 [i + j] = '\0';
  return (i + j);
}
```

Comment: `s1 != '\0'` does not mean what you think it means.  It looks like you want `s1[i] != '\0'`.  Similarly with s2.

Comment: What's the difference between the two? They look the same. I'm trying to run the loop until it reaches the \0 character at the end.

Comment: The fact that yours does not depend on the iteration variable, `i`, should be a big red flag.  The difference is that yours compares the *pointer* `s1` with '\0' whereas mine compares one of the characters in the array to which `s1` points.

Comment: `s1` is a pointer to a `char`, `s1[i]` is a character in your string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in these lines:

```
for (j = i; s2 != '\0'; ++j)
  s1[j] = s2[j];
```

Here `j` is not zero, so you start indexing in `s2` at a non-zero index, possible even running out of bounds.

But that's only *one* problem. The second problem is the condition of the loop, it will *never* be false leading to an infinite loop.

The first loop has the same problem with the loop condition.

As for *why* the loop condition is wrong, the character `'\0'` is equal to zero which is also on most systems equal to `NULL`. So you are effectively checking if e.g. `s1 != NULL`. Since both strings are compile-times arrays the pointers passed to the functions will never bel null pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues, mainly with the condition in the for loops:

```
for (i = 0; s1 != '\0'; ++i)
```

unless the string is null, this will never be true.

What you want to put instead is

```
for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i)
```

this checks if the character you're looking at is the null terminating char, which is probably what you wanted.

The second loop is also a problem.

```
for (j = i; s2 != '\0'; ++j)
s1[j] = s2[j];
```

You're starting s2 at j, not at zero

```
for (j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; ++j)
s1[i + j] = s2[j];
```

This walks you through s2, adding s2[0] to s1[i], where s1[i] is the null character from your last for loop. Then you increment j, and then s1[i+1] becomes s2[1], and so on.

**Additionally:**

Appending the null character can (possibly) be done as :

```
for (j = 0; s2[j-1] != '\0'; ++j)
s1[i + j] = s2[j];
```

if you know FOR SURE that the character before s2 is not null, this can be done by declaring:

```
char array1[MAX_SZ * 2];
char placeholder = 0xff
char array2[MAX_SZ];
```

if that didn't make sense, ignore it too and append the null char the way you were doing it before